# Statistics for posts from unregistered versus registered accounts

Tags: feature-request, support, moderator-tools, unregistered-users, analytics

I would like to have statistics for the quality of posts coming from unregistered versus registered accounts on my site.

It is my suspicion that people who are willing to put out the effort to register an account will also put more effort into writing good questions; I'd like to see some evidence for or against this.

I also suspect that on my site the vast majority of good questions and answers come from registered users, but again I'd like to see some data.

Is this already possible through the Data Explorer?  If so, how?  If not consider this a feature request.

Comment: There may be some data from when SO moved to requiring registration somewhere on [metase] or on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User type doesn't seem to be exposed in Data Explorer. That sucks.

So... I'm gonna define a "bad" post as one that has been closed, deleted (by someone other than the author), or down-voted below zero.  Analyzing the past 60 days worth of Mathematica *questions* gives:

```
Registered Unregistered Registered Badness Unreg Badness PctRegBad PctUnregBad 
---------- ------------ ------------------ ------------- --------- ----------- 
1333       124          333                55            24.98     44.35
```

...and the past 60 days worth of Mathematica *answers* produces:

```
Registered Unregistered Registered Badness Unreg Badness PctRegBad PctUnregBad 
---------- ------------ ------------------ ------------- --------- ----------- 
1662       17           45                 13            2.71      76.47
```

See also: [Requiring registration to ask questions - did it made a difference?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/requiring-registration-to-ask-questions-did-it-made-a-difference)

Comment: Follow-up question: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1079/121

Comment: Which queries can I use to get this data for my site?

Comment: Well, two options right now, @Michael: post a request for 'em on your meta, or post a feature-request here to get UserType into SEDE so you can self-serve.

Comment: [Done.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5838/126632)